# Catch error on Msg ID #

Tags: vb.net

With Try/Catch is there a way to catch a MSSQL error by Msg ID? I want to catch a 208 when a table is not found and then create it. I found mockup code in C# but nothing VB.NET wise as to how to grab the Error ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Try 
   'Some statment
Catch sqlEx as SqlException When sqlEx.Number = [SQL error number] 
   'Some error handling for that exception 
Catch sqlEx as SqlException When sqlEx.Number = [Another SQL error number]
   'Some other handling for that exception
Catch sqlEx as SqlException
   'Do something else for the other sql exceptions 
Catch ex as Exception 
   Throw 'if there is another exception it might be a good idé to retrow it
End Try
```

Comment: @AmanadaSmith : Remember to up vote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling:P